# Is it possible to call a JET file within another JET file? If so please explain how it can be done

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, code-generation, eclipse-m2t-jet

I have a JET file generating a C++ file. I want to generate various C++ files out of a single JET file.The single jet file should call other JET files within it. Is it possible?

Comment: any more information to share? any code-samples ?

Comment: No Code Samples.But I read Excel files into Templates and generate a C++file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  You do this with the ws:file tag:

```
    <ws:file path="" template="" replace="true" />
```

Generally this is done in the main.jet file and is discouraged in other jet templates, but is doable.  In order to use the ws tag library in any jet template, you'll need to use the tab lib directive for the ws library:

```
<%@taglib prefix="ws" id="org.eclipse.jet.workspaceTags" %>
```

This directive is written to the top of the main.jet by default (but not to other jet templates) by the tooling.